# Hashcat doesn't recognize my gpu

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, gpu, amdgpu, hash

I Have an **AMD RX 580 GPU** which i want to *crack some hashes using HASH CAT*. Despite installing ROCm & AMDGPU (which are the requirements to crack hashes using an AMD GPU), It does not recognize my GPU and therefore i cannot crack hashes using it. **Yes, I Could just crack them using my CPU, but it takes ages to do that, so i prefer using the GPU.**

SPECS:
**AMD RADEON RX 580 GPU**

**INTEL CORE I5-9400F**

Comment: Can you add your Ubuntu version (`lsb_release -a`), if you're using Ubuntu. Kernel version (`uname -a`) would also be useful